# a SET of wordpress native galleries with title and text?

Tags: functions, gallery

[image: graphic structure]How to make it in the simpliest way ?

see graphic structure,

-a SET of items in wordpress page -and EVERY item is: one gallery (the best solution -> wp native gallery) on left, with title and description on right

Comment: I don’t see any graphic.

Comment: hello Jacob, you dont' see this ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfrpM.jpg

Comment: Can't you just use a columns block with 2 columns? Put a gallery block in the left column, and title/text in the right column?

Comment: I want to make it WITHOUT gutenberg. Optimal solution is to have native wp gallery with two additional boxes in gallery edit: title and rest (text with subheads )